# Change color of UINavigationController back button

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I'm having problems trying to figure out how to change the color of the buttons on the navigation controller.

Previously I had used the following:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:226/255.0 green:66/255.0 blue:66/255.0 alpha:0.0]];
```

and this worked, but I added a new view with a toolbar, and the tool bar button images will not show.  If I remove the global coloring, the tool bar items show just fine.

I've tried setting the tint color on both the **leftBarButtonItem** and the **backBarButtonItem** in the **viewDidLoad** method of the view, but both of those properties appear to be null.

I don't want to change the color of the entire navigation bar, just the buttons.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I'll just post this as an answer. Your alpha is set to 0. So you're basically saying the same thing as [UIColor clearColor]. 
Not sure how that ever worked to give you a tint color on your bar button items.

Answer (score 0):

In swift, it can be accomplished by the following command:

```
if let navController = self.navigationController
{
    navController.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
}
```